# Is Azure's TTS Speech Rate and Pitch done in post processing?

Tags: text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Azure's TTS service and was wondering if the rate and pitch values are applied to the audio files after generating a base sound, or are they part of the AI algorithm that generates the base sound?

I would like to know the above because it affects the choice of sampling (and available voices) for the generated files. For instance - if I generate a sound file at 24kHz, which is *later* stretched based on the settings (rate, pitch) there will be some loss of quality compared to a sound file generated at 48kHz which is then post processed. If, however, the rate, and pitch, are part of the AI algorithm the sound wont suffer quality artifacts.

This is also important because if the sound is processed at a later stage I could just do that with better accuracy in a DAW instead of relying on the settings in the TTS process. If however the algo modifies the sounds based on the settings in the TTS then the quality will be as good as it gets.

Comment: checkout the links which are suitable for the pitch and post processing operations of audio. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp#adjust-prosody

and another document of Neural voice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/custom-neural-voice#the-basics-of-custom-neural-voice

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do these operations:

1. Create a custom voice

   a. Open Speech studio

   b. Record the audio

   c. Perform speech synthesizer

[image]

[image]

[image]

To get access click on Apply access. Your organization administrator will give you access on request.

To get complete structure of the operations, check the link mentioned in the comment section.

To perform programmatical manner, follow the below code block and replace the subscription and region details.

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk


def recognize_from_mic():
    # Find your key and resource region under the 'Keys and Endpoint' tab in your Speech resource in Azure Portal
    # Remember to delete the brackets <> when pasting your key and region!
    speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription="", region="westus2")
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config)

    # Asks user for mic input and prints transcription result on screen
    print("Speak into your microphone.")
    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()
    print(result.text)


recognize_from_mic()
```

To Improve synthesis with Speech Synthesis Markup Language. Create an XML file for speech synthesis using the following XML code.

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="URL" xml:lang="string"></speak>
```

To choose voice for text to speech, follow the link mentioned in the comment. To adjust the voice patches and styles follow the link mentioned in the comment to build XML.